# Ubuntu 16.04 ssh-add without ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-agent

I have configured ssh-agent on many older Ubuntu installations, but today, on my new Ubuntu 16.04 setup, I realized that ssh-add has been working, but I never configured my system to run ssh-agent!

Edit: It's not just that I haven't configured it, it is not even running:

```
ps aux | grep ssh
root       976  0.0  0.0  65520  5384 ?        Ss   16:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
user123+  6121  0.0  0.0  21292  1016 pts/1    S+   16:50   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

How is ssh-add working without ssh-agent?  What is this magic?  I see there is a gnome-keyring-daemon running on my system, but open-ssh isn't integrated with gnome is it?

Comment: Some, but not all, systems come with `ssh-agent` configured by default. Look at `ps aux | grep ssh` and `env | grep SSH`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that ssh-agent is not running at all!

Comment: What makes you say this? It very probably is.

Comment: It does not appear in `ps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the `gnome-keyring-daemon` as an alternative (compatible) implementation of an SSH agent.

It is installed through the package `gnome-keyring` and started automatically through `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`.

You can see that which process is your SSH agent with `sudo lsof $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable `SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER` expands to the process that launches the `ssh-agent`.

On my 14.04, by default, after start:

```
% echo "$SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER"
upstart
```

while after killing, and `unset`-ing the variable(s), and then spawning `ssh-agent` again:

```
% echo "$SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER"
## Nothing, not being set
```

So at the startup the `init` process spawns `ssh-agent` directly or indirectly, and the environment variable `SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER` is set accordingly.

Comment: I don't have that env variable set.  I do have `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`, but that is it.

Comment: @HDave Did you kill `ssh-agent` afterwards? Also whats the output of `printenv | grep SSH`?

Comment: On this machine ssh-agent has never run, and I have never killed it.  `printenv | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`

Comment: @HDave You should also at least have `SSH_AGENT_PID`, strange!

Comment: IKR!  WTH! I don't get it...

Comment: @HDave Kill `ssh-agent`, `unset` the environment variable(s), and respawn `ssh-agent`. What happens?